# Salesforce commerce cloud 'dw' is not defined while running lint

Tags: demandware

I get this error when i run `npm run lint`

```
'dw' is not defined while running lint
'request' is not defined while running lint
```

My code:

```
var currentHttpParameterMap = request.httpParameterMap;
var product =dw.catalog.ProductMgr.getProduct(CurrentHttpParameterMap.pid.stringValue);
```

I know why this error comes. It's because local machine doesn't know about dw variable. But it works perfectly on browser.

Any idea to solve this error.

Comment: Normally you should be able to add predefined global variable to your settings of your lint, so it will not throw an error. You just have to make sure that these variable you add are actually always available. Which should be the case with `dw` and `request`

Answer (score 0):

So the answer of my question was below:

Instead

```
var currentHttpParameterMap = request.httpParameterMap;
var product =dw.catalog.ProductMgr.getProduct(CurrentHttpParameterMap.pid.stringValue);
```

Use:

```
var currentHttpParameterMap = request.httpParameterMap;
var ProductMgr = require('dw/catalog/ProductMgr');

var product =ProductMgr.getProduct(CurrentHttpParameterMap.pid.stringValue);
```